# Ionic 4 AngularJS with vanilla JS resources - ng-model doesn't working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using the Ionic 4 with the vanilla js components - pure js injected using the unpkg cdn.

I am trying to make a simple AngularJS binding:

```
<ion-input ng-model="formData.example"></ion-input>
{{formData}}
```

However there nothing in the bindings.

Is there any implementation to make this working made by the Ionic project?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 4 is an Angular 2+ framework. The `ng-model` directive is AngularJS syntax and does not work with Angular 2+ frameworks. Use `([ngModel])="formData.example"`.

For more information, see [Angular forms API Reference -- `ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).